# Making a makefile in C

Tags: c, sockets, dictionary, makefile

I'm actually trying to make a makefile in C but it seems that i get some serious problems for linking all the files together. Basically, I'm trying to make a dictionary which run through a server with sockets. I initialize the dictionary and interpret the request in the file servidor-dict.c and i send the requests from dict.c. I also have those two files :
libjsocket.o which contains the basic fonction to use sockets (j_socket(), j_bind()...).
jsocket.h which is the header of libjsocket.o.

When i run my makefile, the console keep saying me :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_j_socket", referenced from:
      _main in servidor-dict.o
  "_j_bind", referenced from:
      _main in servidor-dict.o
  "_j_accept", referenced from:
      _main in servidor-dict.o
```

So apparently I don't make the correct link between the socket file and my server/client files.
My makefile is the following :

```
CFLAGS= -c -Wall
object= servidor-dict.o libjsocket.o
object1 = dict.o libjsocket.o

tarea: dict servidor-dict 

servidor-dict: $(object)
    gcc -g $(object) -o servidor-dict

dict: $(object1)
    gcc -g $(object1) -o dict

%.o: %.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $<

servidor-dict.c: jsocket.h
dict.c: jsocket.h
libjsocket.c: jsocket.h

clean : 
    rm -rf *.o tarea
```

Comment: Are you sure your makefile says `libsocket.o:` not `libjsocket.o:` (on line 14 above)?  If it says `libsocket.o` then maybe it's finding `libjsocket.o` somewhere else, with different contents.

Comment: Indeed there is an error there. Might be an error I made while testing some others things. But it still not resolves the problem I have... But thank you for making me notice it ;)

Comment: Automatic variables will help you to avoid errors like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to define the `%.o : %.c` rule, and `make` should already know how to use `CFLAGS`.  Putting `-c` in `CFLAGS` can break its use in other places.  Also, the .c files don't depend on the .h files, so perhaps:

If `tarea` is your final program combining all the other .o files:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall

tarea: servidor-dict.o dict.o libjsocket.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $^

servidor-dict.o : servidor-dict.c jsocket.h
dict.o : dict.c jsocket.h
libjsocket.o : libjsocket.c jsocket.h

clean : 
        rm -rf *.o tarea
```

If `servidor-dict` and `dict` were supposed to be your final programs:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall

all : dict servidor-dict
servidor-dict : servidor-dict.o libjsocket.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $^
dict : dict.o libjsocket.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $^

servidor-dict.o : servidor-dict.c jsocket.h
dict.o : dict.c jsocket.h
libjsocket.o : libjsocket.c jsocket.h

clean : 
        rm -rf *.o dict servidor-dict
```

Warning: be certain that's a TAB character doing indentation.

The group of three lines can actually be generated automatically with `gcc -MM *.c`, for example.

Comment: Thank you ! The second code of Makefile you gave me works perfectly ! I think i understood my mistakes now ;). Thank you again for your time !

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple issues here...

- `libsocket.o` should be `libjsocket.o`
- `libjsocket.o` should depend on something (`libjsocket.c`?)
- The rule `servidor-dict.o:` should be `servidor-dict`
- Then the real rule `servidor-dict.o` is missing (you should consider using a magic rule that will handle the generation of all the .o file)

Don't forget to clean after changing your Makefile.

Comment: I just actualize my code following your advices. The strange thing now is that dict build well but not servidor-dict. I checked several times the names and I tried with automatic variables but it doesn't work as well.